# Why Visual Studio Does Not Allow Me to Add A Blank Form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to add a blank form into my C# project, but Visual Studio provides "Inherited" options only.
[image: Screenshot for FAIL to add blank form]

I have ensure that ".Net Desktop Development" component has been installed on my computer.
[image: Screenshot for Visual Studio Installer]

For your information, I can add a blank form into other C# projects successfully.
[image: Screen for SUCCESS to add blank form]

I GUESS this problem is caused by my project.
Do you know what is the problem on my project?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Open your `*.csproj` files and search for differences.

Comment: What's your target framework?

Comment: My (Success and Fail) C# projects are using .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Pretty hard to guess how you did this.  Note that the Web and AspNetCore categories are missing as well.  Only somewhat sensible explanation is that these screenshots were made on different machines and the top one needs to have VS re-installed.

Comment: Hi, [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/86996/view.html) is about C++ but it's the same problem, maybe it helps you? See also [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2017)